# Giving "Author" a custom value instead of the repository username

Tags: svn

Is it possible to have `$Author$` (and as such, `$Id$` too) expanded to a custom name, instead of the username used for authentication?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No not possible. Only the values comming from the committer. Why do you need that?

Comment: Yes, from the committer, that is what I need. Each of our developers has a "matricular number", so if for instance the one with the full name "Foo Bar" and the username "foobar" commits something, we want to have `Foo Bar (<matr.nr.>)` as `$Author$`. It's a project for university, and these are the rules.

Comment: In other words, the replacement is done as usual on the client, I don't have administrative access to the server anyway.